# Strings in BigEndianStructure

Tags: python, ctypes, endianness

I want to do something like that:

```
from ctypes import *

class Packet(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("length", c_ushort),
                ("session", c_uint),
                ("command", c_ushort)]

class PacketString(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("length", c_ushort),
                ("value", c_char_p)]

class InitialPacket(Packet):
    _fields_ = [("time", PacketString)]
```

However I getting error because c_char_p can only be in native byte order. But maybe there is some other way how I can make strings whose length is specified right before them. I just like how structs are easy to read from/write to socket. And how you define just _fields_ and then can use it like that:

```
initialPacket = InitialPacket()
initialPacket.command = 128
```

The question is: How do I create variable-length field in BigEndianStructure? Because Python wouldn't allow me to use c_char_p. Script simply wont run at all. This is error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PKOEmu\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    class PacketString(BigEndianStructure):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\_endian.py", line 34, in __setattr__
    fields.append((name, _other_endian(typ)) + rest)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\_endian.py", line 24, in _other_endian
    raise TypeError("This type does not support other endian: %s" % typ)
TypeError: This type does not support other endian: <class 'ctypes.c_char_p'>
```

Comment: Characters don't have byte order, since a character is only a single byte. Maybe the error is that the `c_ushort` is in the wrong byte order, so you're trying to read 1MB of a 16-character string? It's hard to know what's actually happening unless you show us the relevant code and input values and the actual error you get. Please try to create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @abarnert, actually that is a full example. It wont event run. But it will if I'll comment `("value", c_char_p)` line. This is error I get: `Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    class PacketString(BigEndianStructure):
 File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\_endian.py", line 34, in __setattr__
    fields.append((name, _other_endian(typ)) + rest)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\_endian.py", line 24, in _other_endian
    raise TypeError("This type does not support other endian: %s" % typ)
TypeError: This type does not support other endian: <class 'ctypes.c_char_p'>`

Comment: OK, are you trying to stick an inline string into `PacketString`, or a pointer to a string somewhere in memory? Because what you're doing is the latter. Since your memory is native-endian, and nobody else's memory means anything, there's no way a big-endian pointer could be useful.

Comment: @abarnert, I'm not trying to stick anything yet. I'm stuck on a step where I need to create a valid structure. I added final question to the end of the first post. Script simply wont run if any not-native byte order structure are using c_char_p.

Comment: As I explained, a `ushort` plus a `c_char_p` is not a variable-length structure; it's a fixed-sized length, and a fixed-sized pointer to a string somewhere else in memory. If you want a string in-line, it has to be an array.

Comment: @abarnert, Yeah, thanks to your answer I understand that now. But struct hack works only for last element in struct, isn't it? So I cannot use it. Guess pack/unpack my only option then.

Comment: Well, `value` _is_ the last element in your struct, so that's not a problem. But there are plenty of other problems that make this a bad approach. `pack`/`unpack` is probably a better option—or, even better, wrappers around `pack`/`unpack` that can read and write values of your types directly from/to the stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type:

```
class PacketString(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("length", c_ushort),
                ("value", c_char_p)]
```

… doesn't do what you think it does, even ignoring the endianness issue. It's a struct that contains a ushort length, and then a pointer to the actual string data somewhere else in memory.

In other words, it's just like this C structure:

```
struct PacketString {
    unsigned short length;
    char *value;
};
```

What you're looking for is a length-prefixed string, where the string is directly inline inside the struct. For that, the C structure is:

```
struct PacketString {
    unsigned short length;
    char value[1];
};
```

This is called the "struct hack". This is not actually legal C, but it happens to work with every known C89 compiler, and most C99 and C++ compilers. See the [C FAQ entry](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html) fro details.

So, can you do the same thing in `ctypes`? Well, yes, but it's not as useful:

```
class PacketString(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("length", c_ushort),
                ("value", c_char * 0)]
```

This can get complicated; see [Variable-sized data types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#variable-sized-data-types) in the docs for details. In particular, you can't call `resize` on `p.value`; you need to calculate how much to resize `p` itself, and then change the type of `p._fields_[1]` to the have the right type, and then…

Well, this is why the docs say:

> Another way to use variable-sized data types with ctypes is to use the dynamic nature of Python, and (re-)define the data type after the required size is already known, on a case by case basis.

In other words:

```
class LocalPacketString(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("length", c_ushort),
                ("value", c_char * length)]
ps = LocalPacketString(length, buff)
```

However, you may notice that this isn't really saving you much work over just keeping the types separate.

---

In summary, the struct hack isn't even valid C, and it doesn't map very well to `ctypes`. A `ctypes.Structure` is not a good way to represent a variable-length length-prefixed string.

Comment: And how to resize field inside a struct? I tried this: `initialPacket = InitialPacket()
resize(initialPacket.time.value, 5)` But got error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    resize(initialPacket.time.value, 5)
TypeError: excepted ctypes instance`

Comment: I think the struct module is more convenient for working with data packets.

Comment: @eryksun, Can you advice how to make length-prefixed string in struct module? Or even length-prefixed byte sequence?

Comment: @bobby: A string of length 10 is `'10s'`. If it's a variable length use `'%ds' % length`, i.e. `struct.pack('>HIHH%ds' % length, ...)`

Comment: @bobby: The reason that didn't work is that `initialPacket.time.value` is a `str`, not a `c_char_Array_0`. I tried to update the answer to show how you could begin to approach the problem… but really, you shouldn't, you should use a different alternative. Build your classes as wrappers around `struct` instead of `ctypes` and everything will be a lot easier.