# Python ctypes definition with C struct arrary

Tags: python, ctypes

How to represent C structure like below to python ctypes and access it? It has array of struct as an element with-in another struct.

```
struct hello {
               __s64 f1;
               __u64 f2;
               __u64 f3;
               __s32 f4;
               __u32 f5;
           };

struct world {
               __u64 f1;
               __u64 f2;
               __u16 f3;
               __u16 f4;
               __u32 f5;
               struct hello h[0];
           };
```

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
from ctypes import *

class hello(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [ ("f1", c_longlong),
                 ("f2", c_ulonglong),
                 ("f3", c_ulonglong),
                 ("f4", c_long),
                 ("f5", c_ulong)
              ]
class world(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [ ("f1", c_ulonglong),
                 ("f2", c_ulonglong),
                 ("f3", c_uint16),
                 ("f4", c_uint16),
                 ("f5", c_uint32),
                 ("f6", hello)  #Is this correct? 
              ]
```

Comment: Related, but not sure if it's a dup: [Strings in BigEndianStructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559176/strings-in-bigendianstructure/17559594#17559594)

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is not correct. For the last member of `world` to be an array of N `hello`s, it has to be of type `hello * N`, not `hello`.

But here, N is 0, so that doesn't really work.

In C, this is called the "struct hack" or "struct array hack". That `world` struct isn't a real structure that you can construct as-is and pass around. Instead, what you do is malloc up `sizeof(world) + N * sizeof(hello)` bytes, cast that to `world *`, and pass that pointer around. Because array indexing doesn't do any type-checking in C, `my_world->h[2]` will just work (assuming you've allocated enough memory for at least 3 `hello`s at the end of the `world`).

But it won't work in Python.

Well, it *sort of* works, but you have to do more work.

---

The first option is to not actually define `world` globally, and instead define a new `Structure` class every time you want to deal with a `world`.

For example. let's say we called some function that told us how many hellos there are:

```
n = lib.number_of_hellos()
```

And now we want to call a function that gives us the world with that many hellos in it. So:

```
class world(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [ ("f1", c_ulonglong),
                 ("f2", c_ulonglong),
                 ("f3", c_uint16),
                 ("f4", c_uint16),
                 ("f5", c_uint32),
                 ("f6", hello * n)
              ]
```

At this point, you can either change the `restype` of `lib.get_world` to return a `POINTER(world)`, or you can cast the result that comes back.

---

Alternatively, you can define `world` as always having 1 `hello`, but then, instead of accessing `hello` directly off a `world` pointer, you construct a `hello * N` pointer at the `hello`'s address (or just at the `world`'s address plus the offset of the type's `hello`; either way is the same).

---

What if you need to create a world with N `hello`s in it to pass to C?

You can use the first trick again, constructing a new `world` class that ends with an array of N `hello`s, then create an instance of that to pass it to C.

Or you can use the same trick C code uses: keep the global single-`hello` `world` class around, and either construct your `world` objects by creating a buffer and then casting that to a `world`, or by constructing a `world` object but then calling `resize` on it.

---

There are also workarounds you can do to make life easier. For example, if you're writing the C code yourself (and you can't just not use the struct hack), you can easily add a pair of C functions that compose a no-`hello` `world`, an array of `hello`s, and a count into an N-`hello` `world`, and vice-versa.

Or, alternatively, just make a `nonhackyworld` type that has a pointer to an array of hellos at the end, instead of directly including it, and write C functions to convert back and forth between them.

Then you just `ctypes` up those functions and call them whenever you want to pass or process a `world` (or even set them up as value type converters for other functions).

Even if you can't add C functions, you can write those functions in `ctypes`. They'll be horribly ugly messes of creating buffers and casting pointers, but you only have to write them (and debug the segfaults) once, and then use them everywhere.